# Comparisons across multiple rows in Stata (household dataset)

Tags: loops, row, stata

I'm working on a household dataset and my data looks like this:

```
 input id   id_family   mother_id   male
        1           2          12      0
        2           2          13      1
        3           3          15      1
        4           3          17      0
        5           3           4      0
 end
```

What I want to do is identify the mother in each family. A mother is a member of the family whose `id` is equal to one of the `mother_id`'s of another family member. In the example above, for the family with `id_family`=3, individual 5 has `mother_id`=4, which makes individual 4 her mother.

I create a family size variable that tells me how many members there are per family. I also create a rank variable for each member within a family. For families of three, I then have the following piece of code that works:

```
bysort id_family: gen family_size=_N
bysort id_family: gen rank=_n

gen mother=. 
bysort id_family: replace mother=1 if male==0 & rank==1 & family_size==3 & (id[_n]==id[_n+1] | id[_n]==id[_n+2])
bysort id_family: replace mother=1 if male==0 & rank==2 & family_size==3 & (id[_n]==id[_n-1] | id[_n]==id[_n+1])
bysort id_family: replace mother=1 if male==0 & rank==3 & family_size==3 & (id[_n]==id[_n-1] | id[_n]==id[_n-2])
```

What I get is:

```
id  id_family   mother_id   male    family_size rank    mother  
1        2          12       0           2        1       .      
2        2          13       1           2        2       .      
3        3          15       1           3        1       .      
4        3          17       0           3        2       1      
5        3           4       0           3        3       .
```

However, in my real data set, I have to get the `mother` for families of size 4 and higher (up to 9), which makes this procedure very inefficient (in the sense that there are too many row elements to compare "manually").

How would you obtain this in a cleaner way? Would you make use of permutations to index the rows? Or would you use a for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using merge.

```
// create sample data
clear
input id id_family mother_id male
        1           2          12      0
        2           2          13      1
        3           3          15      1
        4           3          17      0
        5           3           4      0
end
save families, replace
clear

// do the job
use families
drop id male
rename mother_id id
sort id_family id
duplicates drop
list, clean abbreviate(10)
save mothers, replace
use families, clear
merge 1:1 id_family id using mothers, keep(master match)
generate byte is_mother = _merge==3
list, clean abbreviate(10)
```

The second list yields

```
       id   id_family   mother_id   male            _merge   is_mother  
  1.    1           2          12      0   master only (1)           0  
  2.    2           2          13      1   master only (1)           0  
  3.    3           3          15      1   master only (1)           0  
  4.    4           3          17      0       matched (3)           1  
  5.    5           3           4      0   master only (1)           0
```

where I retained _merge only for expositional purposes.